# What are the requirements for performing a counterfactual inference?

Tags: causality

Can someone point me towards a review of philosophical literature that covers the requirements for inferring a counterfactual outcome?

Comment: It seems this article has good starting points: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a review of philosophical literature that covers the requirements for inferring a counterfactual outcome:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/#LatDev